# How do I download vader_lexicon through NLTK in jupyter

Tags: python, nltk, jupyter

I know I can use:

`nltk.download()`

But I really don't want to waste time letting the whole thing download. How do I just install the `vader_lexicon`

Comment: Use the command: 1) !pip install nltk   then 2) nltk.download('vader_lexicon')

Comment: 1) !pip install nltk 2) import nltk 3) nltk.download('vader_lexicon')

Answer (score 4):

Use `nltk.download()` in Python with/without Jupyter:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
[nltk_data] Downloading package vader_lexicon to
[nltk_data]     /Users/liling.tan/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package vader_lexicon is already up-to-date!
True
```

Or on terminal:

```
$ python -m nltk.downloader vader_lexicon
[nltk_data] Downloading package vader_lexicon to
[nltk_data]     /Users/liling.tan/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package vader_lexicon is already up-to-date!
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following command in command prompt/terminal

```
python -m nltk.downloader vader_lexicon
```

Output for Windows:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package vader_lexicon to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
```

It will download only the specific package to `nltk_data` folder.